# Gmail to Gmail through Mandrill

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, mandrill

I need Mandrill service for sending confirmation emails.
My "from" account is a Business Gmail.
Everything works fine when I send an email to a domain that is NOT gmail, indeed when I point to a gmail.com mailbox, no mail arrives.
Mandrill dashboard report "Delivered" with green light.
I double checked the spam.

Is Gmail blocking send to Gmail passing through external SMTP?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Mandrill, you should be able to click on the 'Delivered' link to see whether Gmail accepted the message for delivery. If you're using a Google Apps domain, you may want to set up SPF and DKIM for Mandrill to be sure Mandrill is authorized to send on behalf of your domain as well.